# Smart Contract Working on Remix but not TestNet

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ropsten, rinkeby

This question has been asked before. however, those answers did not help me. (of course, I now can't find the "answer" atm) It said that Ropsten (what I was currently using) has fewer miners - or something to that extent, and therefore isn't the best to run smart contract. They recommended Rinkeby. I tried that, but it did not work either :( Currently, all functions work on Remix.

Here' some info about my Rinkeby and Ropsten:

I have two main functions, the first is `PickYourNumbers()` which allows you to pick numbers, put them into an array, and then displays them on the contract with `GetHash()`. This one works.

The second is `StartTheLotto()` which calls the function `random()`. This function generates... a random number. It calls this function 6 times, setting 6 vars in an array to different random numbers. Lastly, the array is displayed via `lottoWinners()`.

I am guessing it is because I am having the contract/miners do too much? Do you have any recommendations?

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract EthereumLottery {

    uint[6] array;
    uint[6] winners;
    string warning = "please be sure to bet below 67 for the first 5 balls and 34 for the 6th";
    address owner;    // current owner of the contract
    uint addr = address(this).balance;
    uint nonce = 1;
    uint startTime = now;

    constructor() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function WARNING() public view returns (string memory) {
        return warning;
    }

    function PickYourNumbers(uint8 firstBall, uint8 secondBall, 
      uint8 thirdBall, uint8 fourthBall, 
      uint8 fithBall, uint8 powerballllll) public {

        if (firstBall <= 66) array[0] = firstBall;
        if (secondBall <= 66) array[1] = secondBall;
        if (thirdBall <= 66) array[2] = thirdBall;
        if (fourthBall <= 66) array[3] = fourthBall;
        if (fithBall <= 66) array[4] = fithBall;
        if (powerballllll <= 66) array[5] = powerballllll;

    }

    function GetHash() public view returns (uint[6] memory) {
        return array;
    }

    function StartTheLotto() public returns (uint[6] memory) {
        nonce++;
        winners[0] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[1] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[2] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[3] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[4] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[5] = random();
    }


    function lottoWinners() public view returns (uint[6] memory) {
        return winners;
    }

    function random() private view returns(uint) {

        uint interval = now - startTime;

        bytes32 randomNum = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(interval + nonce + tx.gasprice + addr));

        uint number;
        for(uint i=0;i<randomNum.length;i++){
            number = number + uint(randomNum[i])*(2**(8*(randomNum.length-(i+1))));
        }
        return number % 67;
    }

}
```

edit:

Rinkeby DAPP Addr: 0x75AB85fB72Ba93c9a9dF23E6FC775b58Dc7f050B

Ropsten DAPP Addr: 0x8bea60c97DC6BD955a614C58e5D0A0fBD12a8593

Comment: What's the deployed contract address on Ropsten?

Comment: [0x8bea60c97DC6BD955a614C58e5D0A0fBD12a8593](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8bea60c97dc6bd955a614c58e5d0a0fbd12a8593)

Comment: I can see it was deployed. What is the actual problem? Can you elaborate on "Doesn't work"?

Comment: It doesn't consume excessive gas in Remix and there is bytecode at that address, so I think the focus should be on testing methodology - what you use, how you use it, do you have Rinkeby Eth to pay for gas, is the account unlocked, etc.

Comment: @RobHitchens the problem is that when I run `StartTheLotto()` I, without fail, receive [Warning! Error encountered during contract execution](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6580cae2056ad89063b3bbdf63fa54f7d20dcbdf2e1be0edd383f5c011def90c) - even with 10+ Ether

Comment: This lottery allows the caller of `random` to exactly choose the winners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of recoding and freaking out... haha... I noticed something peculiar. When I executed (order 66 ha) `PickYourNumbers()` in the "latest transactions" (bottom of mist wallet) it said `Contract execution`. But when I executed `StartTheLotto()` it said `Transfer between accounts`.

I then decided get user input for the second function, so instead of `StartTheLotto()` I did `StartTheLotto(int8 asdf)` and adjusted accordingly. Now, for some weird reason the function works and displays `Contract execution`. I would love it if someone could elaborate better than I could so I could have the why and not just the how.

new code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract EthereumLottery {

    uint[6] array;
    uint[6] winners;
    string warning = "please be sure to bet below 67 for the first 5 balls and 34 for the 6th";
    address owner;
    uint addr = address(this).balance;
    uint nonce = 1;
    uint startTime = now;
    int8 fdsa;              // ADDED THIS VAR TO USE ASDF USR INPUT

    constructor() public {
      owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function WARNING() public view returns (string memory) {
        return warning;
    }

    function PickYourNumbers(uint8 firstBall, uint8 secondBall, 
      uint8 thirdBall, uint8 fourthBall, 
      uint8 fithBall, uint8 powerballllll) public {
        if (firstBall <= 66) array[0] = firstBall;
        if (secondBall <= 66) array[1] = secondBall;
        if (thirdBall <= 66) array[2] = thirdBall;
        if (fourthBall <= 66) array[3] = fourthBall;
        if (fithBall <= 66) array[4] = fithBall;
        if (powerballllll <= 66) array[5] = powerballllll;
    }

    function GetHash() public view returns (uint[6] memory) {
        return array;
    }

                   //ADDED USR INPUT HERE
    function StartTheLotto(int8 asdf) public returns (uint[6] memory) {
        fdsa = asdf; // USESD IT SO WOULDN'T THROW ERROR
        nonce++;
        winners[0] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[1] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[2] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[3] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[4] = random();
        nonce++;
        winners[5] = random();
    }


    function lottoWinners() public view returns (uint[6] memory) {
        return winners;
    }

    function random() private view returns(uint) {

        uint interval = now - startTime;

        bytes32 randomNum = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(interval + nonce + tx.gasprice + addr));

        uint number;
        for(uint i=0;i<randomNum.length;i++){
            number = number + uint(randomNum[i])*(2**(8*(randomNum.length-(i+1))));
        }
        return number % 67;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chris,

I took your Solidity code and tried out the same on Rinkeyby test network and it works perfectly for me as expected.

Please cross check :
- that you have enough balance to execute each transaction (function call), you can get test Ethers to use on rinkeby test network from here.

- allow couple of seconds for each transaction to be validated by miners and then refresh the function call, you should see the changed state.

Comment: for my ropsten I have 10 Eth and rinkeby I have 18.75. Whenever run the 'Start The Lotto' (on either network) I recieve `Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]` without fail. [link](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6580cae2056ad89063b3bbdf63fa54f7d20dcbdf2e1be0edd383f5c011def90c). Can I see your contract address?